# What keyboard hymnals do beginner piano accompanists use to learn the Catholic Mass?

Tags: catholicism, mass, music

I'm actually looking for a gift for my wife to buy me for Christmas, but in trying to make this an objective questions for this site, I'd like to know, assuming there is some sort of common underground progression that the accompanists and liturgists make from being relatively crummy amateur piano players (like myself) to being able to crank out "On Eagles Wings" like a virtuoso, are there hymnals that are easier for pianists?  Our local church has been without an accompanist for several years since the last one reverted to Lutheranism, I'd like to help, but I'm kind of a bummer pianist, as I've mentioned previously, anyway, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

See the

> [*Brebeuf Hymnal Organ Accompaniment*](https://www.sophiainstitute.com/products/item/brebeuf-hymnal-organ-accompaniment) (3-Volume Set)
> by Nicolas Viel Publications

for [Corpus Christi Watershed](https://ccwatershed.org/)'s [*Saint Jean de Brébeuf Hymnal*](https://www.ccwatershed.org/hymn/).

The [Church Music Association of America (CMAA)](https://musicasacra.com)'s [forum](https://forum.musicasacra.com/forum/) might be able to offer other suggestions (or perhaps they already have; do a search).

Comment: Sample pages [here](http://archive.ccwatershed.org/media/pdfs/19/04/25/11-20-37_0.pdf).  The important question is **what hymnal your parish is using**.  In the Catholic parishes I went they use the less traditional [Breaking Bread hymnal](https://www.ocp.org/en-us/collections/dg/11/breaking-bread-todays-missal-and-music-issue-accompaniment-books).

Comment: If your parish is using Breaking Bread, some songs that are contemporary have easier accompaniment if you're not used to play 4-voice accompaniment.  See examples [here](https://dh8zy5a1i9xe5.cloudfront.net/shared/pdf/preview/30143703.pdf): #65 (PDF page 100) is traditional 4-voice like most of the Brebeuf Hymnal but most contemporary songs have a "pop" style accompaniment, which could be easier for you.  Another feature of the BB hymnal accompaniment is that they have the chords, so if you can play the bass line on your left and the chords on your right hand.